# tmPlot is in namespace, but its dependencies are not found

Tags: r, namespaces, treemap

I have a package which uses the `tmPlot` function from `treemap`, but when I try to use the function, it throws an error that one of its dependencies isn't loaded:

```
Error in tmPlot(data, index = index, vSize = vSize) : 
  could not find function "brewer.pal"
```

The dependency is installed and in the namespace.

This question has a little bit of setup, being a package problem, but I've tried to make it as minimal as possible:

**Ensure you have `treemap` (and all its dependencies) installed.**

**I've made a directory called 'anRpackage'. Inside it is a folder ('R') and a DESCRIPTION file with the following text:**

```
Package: anRpackage
Title: What the package does (short line)
Version: 1.0
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: Who to complain to <yourfault@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: What license is it under?
Imports:
    treemap
Collate:
    'maketree.R'
```

**Inside the R/ folder is a single R file called 'maketree.R'. Its contents are:**

```
#' maketree
#' 
#' @importFrom treemap tmPlot
#' @export maketree

maketree <-
function(data, index, vSize){
  tmPlot(data, index=index, vSize=vSize)
}
```

**Assuming you're in the directory above 'anRpackage', run the following script:**

```
library(roxygen2)
roxygenise("anRpackage/")

library(devtools)

build("anRpackage")
install("anRpackage")
```

**Restart R (preferably with --vanilla) and run the following:**

```
library(anRpackage)

data(mtcars)
maketree(mtcars, "cyl", "mpg")
```

You should get the error I described right at the beginning. Why does this happen? `RColorBrewer` is listed as Depends for `treemap`, so it should be be automatically imported, should it not?

Comment: Try adding `import RColorBrewer`.  This package may not be loaded automatically by `treemap` or maybe it does but calling just the one function from tree map doesn't call `RColorBrewer`.

Comment: @TylerRinker It's not so much that I want any fix for the problem (the problem can easily be fixed by adding `library(treemap)` in the function). It's more that I want to know why this problem is happening here when, by my understanding, it should not happen. I don't understand why some packages need to be loaded manually and not others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is really with treemap. `treemap` uses `brewer.pal`, and so should `Imports: RColorBrewer` and `importFrom(RColorBrewer, brewer.pal)`.

As it stands now, everything is ok if the user says `library(treemap)`, treemap and RColorBrewer are attached to the `search()` path, and when `tmPlot` is evaluated `brewer.pal` is found on the search path. Of course the package would break if the user were to say `brewer.pal="yeast"` or something, because the wrong symbol would be found; this is one of the reasons for a name space, to protect treemap's functions from what the user might do.

But what happens when you (correctly) Imports: treemap? treemap is loaded (into memory) but neither treemap nor its dependencies are attached (to the search path). So `brewer.pal` is not found.

If treemap were to Imports: RColorBrewer, then brewer.pal would be found both when treemap were attached to the search path by a call to `library(treemap)`, and when only imported into your package.

Contact the maintainer of treemap and ask them to do a more careful job of constructing their name space.

Comment: Very nicely explained. I need to contact a couple of package maintainers with just this request, and wonder if there's a canonical document to point them to -- something particularly good in the R docs, on the CRAN website, or the R-devel list-serve. Now I may just use your answer instead. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, nice explanation +1

Comment: So is the main problem that they're using Depends rather than Imports or that their NAMESPACE is missing the appropriate statements?

Comment: @sebastian-c For this particular issue, treemap should be using Imports: RColorBrewer in DESCRIPTION (and probably not Depends: RColorBrewer -- treemap end-users do not need to use RColorBrewer functions directly), and adding importFrom(RColorBrewer, brewer.pal) to their NAMESPACE. From a quick glance there are additional packages / symbols that should be imported.

Comment: @MartinMorgan I contacted the author of the package and he informs me that this is to be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

before calling the `tmPlot(data, index = index, vSize = vSize)`, you need to load RColorBrewer:

```
require(RColorBrewer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the fact that you use `Imports` instead of `Depends` in your `DESCRIPTION` file.

If you use `Depends: treemap`, the `treemap` package is loaded and attached when you load your package, and as such the `treemap` dependencies are loaded too.

If you use `Imports: treemap`, then only the specified namespace is imported, ie you can use the `treemap` variables in your functions. But it seems that in this case the `treemap` dependencies are not loaded.

So I think you should either use `Depends: treemap` (but it seems that the use of `Imports` is promoted these days), or import `RColorBrewer` directly from your package.

Sorry, not sure this really answers your question, and you may be already perfectly aware of all of these points...