# How do I prevent "r 'library' or 'require' calls not declared" warnings when developing a package?

Tags: r

I'm developing a package that depends on package `foo`, and in my package code there is a call to a function exported from `foo`. I've included the package name in the `NAMESPACE` with an `import(foo)` declaration, and also under the `Imports:` line in the `DESCRIPTION` file. However, I get the following warning when running `R CMD check`:

```
r 'library' or 'require' calls not declared from: 'foo'
```

What am I missing?

There is a similar question at [Loading depending packages using .onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294679/loading-depending-packages-using-onload), but it doesn't seem to discuss this specific warning.

Answer (score 50):

The most likely candidate is that your functions contain unnecessary calls to `require(<pkg>)` or `library(<pkg>)`. The error message is a bit misleading -- it's telling you that you've placed `require` or `library` calls in your code, but haven't actually (properly) declared those calls in your `DESCRIPTION` file.

If your intention was to use code from those packages in your own package, then you don't need these `library` / `require` calls; rather, you need to properly declare that you're using those packages (and how you're using them) in your `DESCRIPTION` file.

Most likely, you want to 'import' the package and make some, or all, of its exported functions / symbols available to your package. You can add such packages to the `Imports:` field in your `DESCRIPTION` file -- as e.g.

```
Imports: <pkg>
```

and similarly, declare that you want to use *all* exported symbols from that package by writing, in the `NAMESPACE` file,

```
import(<pkg>)
```

By doing this, all of the functions in `<pkg>`'s namespace are automatically made available and hence it is not necessary to `require` that package anywhere in your code.

Within the context of a package, the main use of `require` is for functions that you would like make available only conditionally. For example, suppose you write a function that handles a very specific plotting method which requires `foo`, but `foo` is otherwise un-needed in your package. So, if you wanted to include code that conditionally depends on package `foo`, you can write something of the form:

```
if (require("foo")) {
  #do stuff
}
```

and then you can include `foo` in the `DESCRIPTION` under `Suggests:` rather than `Imports:`. Another example is a package used in producing a vignette but is never required by the users of your package.

In sum: if you are importing a package only to use the functions exported in that package's namespace, you don't need to `library` or `require` it anywhere in your package code.

EDIT: In newer versions of R, `R CMD check` may warn if you use `require`, and instead suggest you use `requireNamespace`. In that case, you can follow the pattern:

```
## Use the 'bar' function from package 'foo'
if (requireNamespace("foo", quietly = TRUE)) {
    foo::bar()
}
```

Comment: A noted addition to when you should use `library` or `require` is if the package from which you're importing functions doesn't import its functions properly, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14808337/1465387).

Comment: "then you can include foo in the NAMESPACE under Suggests: rather than Includes:" You mean DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: What difference does it make to put `require()` in a `if` statement? Doesn't it still load the package?

Comment: 1) You're right, my mistake -- changed. 2) `require` returns `FALSE` if the package cannot be loaded (e.g. it does not exist), so wrapping it in an if statement ensures the code block only gets executed if the package can be successfully loaded.

Answer (score 12):

FYI, it's bad form to import all functions of package (when you don't use them) with:

```
@import package
```

Better to just

```
package::thisOne()
```

When you need it, or

```
@importFrom package thisOne
```

If you use a particular function repeatedly

Comment: I wonder how `shiny::runApp` (contains a `require`) passed this check.