# R: selective import with importFrom: namespace issues

Tags: r, import, namespaces, package

I am building an R package and want to get my dependencies right. I use the function `Linp` from the `LIM` package. `LIM` is listed in the 'Imports' field in my `DESCRIPTION` file. I import the function in my `NAMESPACE` file:

```
importFrom("LIM", "Linp")
```

When running `R CMD CHECK` I get an error when the example of the function which uses `Linp` is run:

```
Error: could not find function "linp"
```

So there seems to be `Linp` and `linp`.

The following fails:

```
importFrom("LIM", "linp")
Error : object ‘linp’ is not exported by 'namespace:LIM'
```

because there is no `LIM::linp`. However, there is a `limSolve::linp`, but if I add `limSolve` in `DESCRIPTION` and put the following into my `NAMESPACE`:

```
importFrom("limSolve", "linp")
```

I still get the error:

```
Error: could not find function "linp"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: So... find the section of your code that calls `linp` and change it to `Linp`?

Comment: My code does not call `linp` but `Linp`.

Comment: `R CMD CHECK` says otherwise. You probably have a typo.

Comment: I got it to work by putting `LIM` in `Depends` and not in `Imports` in `DESCRIPTION`.

Comment: @Hong Ooi: `R CMD check`, of course

Comment: I found this in the Bioconductor package instructions: **Depends: is appropriate when a package is used in the example section of a man page.** That is true in my case.

Comment: See the caveat section of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8638902/967840)

Comment: Ah, that's it! Now it becomes clear!