# Pesky ggplot2 namespace conflict when using ggplot2 in package

Tags: r, ggplot2, namespaces, package, cran

I'm contributing to the [qmethod](https://github.com/maxheld83/qmethod) R package, and I just wrote a function that creates a bunch of `ggplot2` objects.

The function works fine, but builds and `R CMD Check` warns me that:

```
replacing previous import by ‘ggplot2::%+%’ when loading ‘qmethod’
```

I've looked at [SE posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343235/using-importfrom-in-roxygen2) and @hadley's [book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) but can't figure out the problem.

Here's the relevant parts of my `NAMESPACE`:

```
import("ggplot2",
   "stringr")
import("psych")
importFrom("plyr","count")
importFrom("reshape2","melt")
importFrom("digest", "digest")
importFrom("RColorBrewer", "brewer.pal")
```

And here's part of my `DESCRIPTION`:

```
Imports:
  digest,
  psych,
  knitr,
  RColorBrewer,
  stringr,
  ggplot2,
  plyr,
  reshape2
```

The part where I call a ggplot2 function inside my function `array.viz.R` looks like this (and more):

```
g <- ggplot(
      data = array.viz.data
      ,aes(
        x = fsc  # factor scores, always same variable bc dataframe is constructed for every factor array by above loop
        ,y = ycoord  # just the random ycoord for viz
        ,ymax = max(ycoord)
        ,ymin = 0
        #,label = item.wrapped  # this for some reason causes an error
      )
    )
    g <- g + geom_tile(  # add background tiles
      aes(
        fill = item.sd
      )
    )
```

Ps.: you can find the entire current work here: https://github.com/maxheld83/qmethod/tree/array-viz

Pps.: I am aware that `ggplot2` itself imports a bunch of the functions I also import (such as `reshape2`), so I have a hunch that that might be a problem.

Comment: I'm just adding this link as a reference for the source of the warning: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a6e088d02a6fb54c42cfe384865ea6788c24a900/src/library/base/R/namespace.R#L836-L842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, `import("psych")` is the offending package.

It seems to somehow export again `ggplot::%+%`, though I can't think of why that would be the case.

Anyway, the fix is:

```
importFrom("psych", "principal")  # that's the function we were using
```