# Package "Imports" not loading in R development package

Tags: r, import, dependencies, package

I am building a package in `R` in a windows environment using `Rstudio`, `devtools` `roxygen2` and `Rtools`.

The package is showing no problems in `R CMD CHECK`. However when I try to load the package using `library("mypkg")`, the packages specified under `Imports` in `DESCRIPTION` are not being loaded (`Loading required package:` message is not there). On using `pkgDepends("mypkg")`, the `$Depends` is shown as `character(0)`.

I have to load the required packages using `library()` for `mypkg` to function.

I am using *namespace imports* instead of `package::function()` syntax. All the required packages are there in the `NAMESPACE` as `imports()`.

Why is this happening? How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the correct behaviour.  `Imports` just means that code inside your package can see the functions that you import from other packages.  The other packages aren't placed on the `search` path like with `Depends`.

Further reading:
[Better explanation of when to use Imports/Depends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637993/better-explanation-of-when-to-use-imports-depends)

Comment: That is what I understood. But for a package, the `Imports` packages are also loaded. For Example in case of the package [`stringdist`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html), `parallel` is given under `Imports`. But when we load it by `library("stringdist")`, the message `Loading required package: parallel` appears and `parallel` is also loaded.

Comment: I don't get that message with `stringdist 0.8.2`/`R 3.1.2`/`Win7 and Red Hat'. What version of `stringdist`/R/OS are you using?  Are you sure that the message didn't occur after you ran another command?

Comment: `stringdist 0.8.0`/`R 3.0.2`/`Win7`. I restarted R tried it. Still getting the same message.

Comment: Got it.. For stringdist 0.8.0 `parallel` is in `Depends`. So I guess I should use `Depends` instead of `Imports`.