# R: use magrittr pipe operator in self written package

Tags: r, namespaces, magrittr

I would like to use the pipe-operator `%>%` introduced in the `magrittr` package in a package I wrote myself to chain `dplyr` data transformations. `magrittr` is listed as `Import` in the `DESCRIPTION` file. After loading my own package and testing the function which uses the pipe-operator I get the following error message:

> Error in functionname(parameter,  :    could not find function "%>%"

Changing `%>%` to `magrittr::%>%` in the function source code does not help either because the package cannot be built anymore.

Comment: I would advise against the pipe operator inside a function inside a package. It makes debugging a lot harder (the call stack gets insanely deep with the pipe). For packages I'd just overwrite a temporary variable, which makes testing a lot easier (think: R telling you on what line the error occurred). The pipe is fine for interactive use but for programming it can be a burden.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It should have worked correctly if you had `magrittr` listed in `Depends`. However, this is [not advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637993/better-explanation-of-when-to-use-imports-depends). Instead, you leave `magrittr` in `Imports` and add the following line to `NAMESPACE`:

```
importFrom(magrittr,"%>%")
```

I suggest reading [Writing R extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html). Your question is covered in paragraphs 1.1.3 and 1.5.1.

Comment: @alexanderketh In that case you should hit the green tick mark next to the answer to mark it as accepted. Welcome to SO!

Comment: If you're using `roxygen2`, you could add `#' importFrom magrittr "%>%"` to have NAMESPACE populated automatically during `roxygenize()`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, just missing @, should be `#' @importFrom magrittr "%>%"`

Comment: Note that this will only allow you to use `%>%` internally in your package. If your API requires users to chain functions using `%>%`, they will still have to explicitly load `magrittr`. One way to solve this problem is to re-export the function. Here is [an example](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/blob/master/R/pipe.R) of how to do it.

Comment: This is also what the usethis package does, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52231630/4627134)

Answer (score 60):

There's now an easier way to support the pipe in your packages. The wonderful package `usethis` has the function `use_pipe()`. You run that function once and it handles everything. This is how the `use_pipe()` function is described in the `usethis` documentation:

> Does setup necessary to use magrittr's pipe internally in your package
>   and to re-export it for users of your package:
>
> Adds magrittr to "Imports" in DESCRIPTION
>
> Creates R/utils-pipe.R with the necessary roxygen template

Comment: Do you add the line `use_pipe()` to the code that you use to build the package? For example, I run: `usethis::use_description(usethis_description);
usethis::use_build_ignore(directories);
usethis::use_build_ignore(paste0(pkg_name, ".Rproj"));
if (file.exists(file.path(pkg_path, "NAMESPACE"))) {
    file.remove(file.path(pkg_path, "NAMESPACE"))
};
devtools::document(pkg_path);
devtools::check(pkg_path);
devtools::load_all(pkg_path);
devtools::install(pkg_path)`.  Would I just add `use_pipe()` at the beginning?

Comment: @Josh you use the `usethis` functions once when you're developing the package. Those functions then add the necessary parts to the build instructions and everything else.

Comment: Would you kindly explain the mechanism of this method? What is the difference between making your package depends on `magrittr` vs `usethis`?

Comment: @aiorr this is basically a shortcut that handles all of the behind-the-scenes work for you. No improvement in functionality compared to manually setting up the settings.

Answer (score 37):

One additional solution - use the `roxygen` package. It's implemented as part of the `devtools` package. Once `devtools` is installed, calling `devtools::document()` will update your `NAMESPACE` for you. It also auto-builds .Rd files with documentation, which is handy.

All you do is add a special comment in the format `#' @import packagename` to a file to import all functions from that package, or `#' @importFrom packagename functionname` to import a function. You can have as many of these comments as you want in your files, so you can have a set of them at the top of each file, or with each of your functions that needs an external function.

Then you run `devtools::document()` and it parses your code looking for those comments, and then it creates an appropriate `NAMESPACE` file for you. Easy.

Comment: When I do this, it messes up the following oxygen comments that pertain to the help file for the first function in the R script.  How do I separate global oxygen comments from the help file ones?

Comment: I usually put the import comments with each function individually. That way if other functions in the file change, your imports stay accurate. So then there are no global definitions.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming that you're using RStudio, Hadley's `devtools` package, and listed `magrittr` in the Imports section of the `DESCRIPTION` file, here are steps I took to make `%>%` work in my package function(s).

First, write function `foo.R`:

```
#' Convert \code{data.frame} to \code{list}.
#' 
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @name %>%
#' @rdname pipe
#' @export
#' @param x A \code{data.frame} object.
#' @examples
#' my_result <- foo(iris)
#'
foo <- function(x) {
    x %>%
        as.list()
}
```

Second, run `devtools::document()`.

Third, run `devtools::load_all()`.

A file like [this](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/blob/master/R/pipe.R) will be created in your `R/` directory and your function should work as expected.

Comment: what is the purpose of `@name %>%` here?