# How to properly use %>% in a package

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I'm creating a package, and I'm trying to be smart about the namespace.  I also heavily use dplyr for just about everything these days.  I understand that I should use:

`dplyr::select()`

However, I'm not sure what I need to do to use the piping operator:

`%>%`

The sample code below makes sense:

`dplyr::select(mtcars, mpg)`

This doesn't (and of course doesn't work):

`mtcars dplyr::%>% dplyr::select(mpg)`

Comment: The `%>%` operator really comes from `magrittr`. Use the solution from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947344/r-use-magrittr-pipe-operator-in-self-written-package

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I didn't find this issue when searching.

Comment: I can imagine search engines have a hard time with `%>%` ;)