# how to import with roxygen packages the pipe operator %>% from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, package, pipe, roxygen2

I want to build a package with some functions i wrote. Now my problem is, that i cannot use the pipe-operator %>% with dplyr. I create the package with roxygen2.

If i write the dplyr-commands without %>%, everything works fine.

inside the code:

```
#'
#' @import dplyr readr mailR writexl
#' @importFrom dplyr %>%
#' @name %>%
#' 
#' @export
#'
```

I wrote:

DESCRIPTION

```
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
Imports: dplyr
```

roxygen2 generates:

NAMESPACE

```
...
importFrom(dplyr,"%>%")
...
```

Comment: `%>%` is from `magrittr` if I'm not mistaking. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947344/r-use-magrittr-pipe-operator-in-self-written-package

Answer (score 6):

Usually you would import the pipe operator from `magrittr`.

You could add a file to the R dir of your package that looks somewhat like this:

```
#' Pipe
#'
#' Put description here
#'
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @name %>%
#' @rdname pipe
#' @export
#' @param lhs,rhs specify what lhs and rhs are
#' @examples
#' # some examples if you want to highlight the usage in the package
NULL
```

In addition you have to add magrittr to your imports in the description file of your package.

Answer (score 2):

The solution posed by @clemens is flexible; it allows you to write your own documentation of the imported command.  If you don't want to write your own documentation, but instead, want your documentation to automatically link to the documentation from the `magrittr` package, use the following code in a file in the R directory of your package to import the pipe:

```
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @export
magrittr::`%>%`
```

If you have the `dplyr` package installed, you can see an example of the default documentation for imported files by entering the following in the R console:

```
?dplyr::`%>%`
```