# use of pipe operator "%>%" using :: in R

Tags: r, pipe

I am building an R package and I am using intensively the pipe operator %>%. I am wandering how to call it from purrr package using :: operator. I have tried `purrr::%>%` but get an error.

I appreciate any guide on this.

P.D: should I call the pipe operator from magrittr rather than purrr?

Comment: `purr::\`%>%\`` should do the trick. why not just import the function?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947344/r-use-magrittr-pipe-operator-in-self-written-package

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `%>%` from `purrr` rather than from `magrittr` or `dplyr`?

Comment: iris purrr::`%>%` summary() is not working

Comment: You can import just the pipe from `magrittr`. I was about to post the same link that @divibisan did, but there's discussion there on imports

Comment: the answer is adressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947344/r-use-magrittr-pipe-operator-in-self-written-package.
Thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best approach is to import it from magrittr and re-export it if you want your users to be able to access it.

Using it internally to your package only, this may work:

```
`%>%` <- purrr::`%>%`
```

check:

```
iris %>% summary
  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
 Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100  
 1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:1.600   1st Qu.:0.300  
 Median :5.800   Median :3.000   Median :4.350   Median :1.300  
 Mean   :5.843   Mean   :3.057   Mean   :3.758   Mean   :1.199  
 3rd Qu.:6.400   3rd Qu.:3.300   3rd Qu.:5.100   3rd Qu.:1.800  
 Max.   :7.900   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500  
       Species  
 setosa    :50  
 versicolor:50  
 virginica :50
```

You cannot use `` purrr::`%>%` `` directly in expressions as the operator needs to be syntactically exposed as a binary operator, i.e. as `%>%` (without qualification).

Answer (score 1):

Starting in R version 4.1.0 there is now a base R pipe operator: `|>`

```
iris |>
  summary()

  Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width          Species  
 Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100   setosa    :50  
 1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:1.600   1st Qu.:0.300   versicolor:50  
 Median :5.800   Median :3.000   Median :4.350   Median :1.300   virginica :50  
 Mean   :5.843   Mean   :3.057   Mean   :3.758   Mean   :1.199                  
 3rd Qu.:6.400   3rd Qu.:3.300   3rd Qu.:5.100   3rd Qu.:1.800                  
 Max.   :7.900   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500
```