# How do I specify that the tidyverse pipe %>% comes from the package tidyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I'm trying to adjust a function I've written to explicitly call on other packages using "::", e.g., `dplyr::mutate`. However, adding the "::" doesn't work for the pipe operator `%>%`. How do I call on that?

This does *not* work:

```
  DF <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:4],
             B = 1:4) magrittr::%>% 
  dplyr::mutate(C = 5)
```

The error I receive is "Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) :
argument ".data" is missing, with no default", so I think that means it's not getting the input of the left-hand data.frame to pipe into the function `mutate`.

Comment: It is from `magritt`

Comment: Ok, thanks, corrected that, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please give a more specific reason other than 'it doesn't work' - it makes it hard to help when we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Can you use https://stackoverflow.com/a/50664286/7547327 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/27947344/7547327 in your function?

Answer (score -1):

I should be:

```
magrittr::`%>%`()
```

Comment: When I tried `DF <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:4], B = 1:4) magrittr::\`%>%\`(dplyr::mutate(C = 5))`, that gives me an "unexpected symbol" error.

Comment: @shirewoman2 You can't pipe if you use ```magrittr::`%>%```. You have to do ```magrittr::`%>%(left, right)```. So you lose the interest of the pipe operator...

Comment: Darn. I use the pipe extensively. No way around it, then?

Comment: @shirewoman2 Don't use `::`, simply. Why do you do that? And you could even avoid the pipe operator for programming, because it is slow. But well, it is nice for readibility, I know.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent :-) For the `::`, I'm following the advice from here for writing a package: https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html. For the `%>%`, yes, I like it for readability. Thanks, though!

Comment: @shirewoman2 This advice is for the readability only. Because with `::`, the reader knows from which package the function comes from. But everybody knows the pipe operator these days. Moreover using `::` is ugly.