# best practices for using bang-bang (!!) and walrus (:=) inside package functions

Tags: r, r-package, rlang

Best practices when writing a new package is to call other package functions using the `package::function()` syntax and keeping the namespace clean. What is the equivalent operation for telling R to use rlang's `!!` and `:=` when I'm using them inside a a package's function, since they have no functional form? Using load_all() things seem to work fine but I want to make sure they're not just working because something else loaded rlang already into my path.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383205/how-to-use-rlang-operators-in-a-package

Comment: @MrFlick: Thank you, the answer to that question does indeed answer this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not need importing:

[From Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#the-polite-fiction-of)

> . !! and !!! behave specially inside all quoting functions powered by rlang, where they behave like real operators with precedence equivalent to unary + and -. This requires considerable work inside rlang, but means that you can write !!x + !!y instead of (!!x) + (!!y).

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55764077/10725960)

> Once an rlang function detects this "operator" it treats it differently to perform the tidy evaluation necessary (which is why the operator is only useful in a rlang context) ... This is why you only need to import the rlang function you want, because the logic for dealing with !! lies inside rlang internals, not a separate function

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55764077/10725960