# Using %>% inside an R package

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, r-package

I am using the pipe operator (%>%) from magrittr (via dplyr) in a package I am developing.

I have run `usethis::use_package("dplyr")`, and this makes the necessary adjustments to import dplyr.

But when running a function that uses the pipe operator, I get the following error:

> Cannot find the function "%>%"

Usually that's because you need to prefix the function by referencing the package it came from e.g., `dplyr::filter`. However, if I call the pipe-operator like: `dplyr::%>%` I get an unexpected token error.

So how do I use the pipe operator in my package?

Comment: 1) Did you try `use_package("magrittr")` instead of `use_package("dplyr")`? 2) To call `%>%` with `::`, wrap it in backticks: `dplyr::\`%>%\``

Comment: [R: use magrittr pipe operator in self written package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947344/r-use-magrittr-pipe-operator-in-self-written-package)

Comment: Yes, 1) gives the same error 2) also gives the same error. It is the "d" of dplr that is not expected i.e consider:   var 2 <- var dplyr::`%>%` dplyr::filter(mode < 2) }

Comment: Ah okay, thanks Henrik. So the answer is to run usethis::use_pipe()

Comment: You can use the new r base pipe.