# ggplot2 - Can't Declare a Variable with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, wt)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, disp)) + geom_point()
p3 <- grid.arrange(p1, p2)
```

Running the code `grid.arrange(p1, p2)` draws a nice plot of p1 and p2 beside each other. I tried to declare this as p3. But if I run p3 I don't get the same nice plot that the `grid.arrange(p1, p2)` gives me. I instead get what's shown below. What's wrong? I want to store `grid.arrange(p1, p2)` as a neat variable like `p3`.

```
p3

TableGrob (2 x 1) "arrange": 2 grobs
  z     cells    name           grob
1 1 (1-1,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
2 2 (2-2,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
```

Comment: `grid::grid.draw(p3)` (ps if you look at the code for `grid.arrange` you see that it calls `arrangeGrob` - which is the plot gtable object - and then uses `grid.draw` to plot it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `grid::grid.draw(p3)` as in:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, wt)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, disp)) + geom_point()
p3 <- grid.arrange(p1, p2)
grid::grid.draw(p3)
```

[image]

Comment: I *think* [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062766/store-output-from-gridextragrid-arrange-into-an-object#comment51466189_29072703) is still relevant.

Comment: @user20650 Thanks for the link.  You should post your answer and I should delete mine. I will delete mine after you see this comment and post your answer. You may also want to point out to not use `plot`