# could not find function - package issue in R

Tags: r, package

I'm make a new package in R. In a function of mine, I called `get_subnetwork` from Package `STRINGdb`, while function `get_subnetwork` called function `graph.data.frame` internally and function `graph.data.frame` is from another package `igraph`.

Here I wanted to make package `STRINGdb` and `igraph` as imports but not depends in the DESCRIPTION of my new package. When I ran the code, it showed

```
Error in load() : could not find function "graph.data.frame"
```

Comment: Use `igraph::graph.data.frame` instead of just `graph.data.frame`.

Comment: @nicola I cannot change the original code of get_subnetwork as graph.data.frame is called internally by get_subnetwork

Comment: @nicola they didn't write the code.  Zhilong - the whole "Function A" "Function B" thing only complicates the issue. If you're going to name the functions anyways just describe the situation using the actual function names.

Comment: @Dason Yes, exactly. Since it involved in a package but not several lines of code, It's not easy to paste the code.

Comment: @Zhilong You're out of luck until those packages change their imports/depends: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637993/better-explanation-of-when-to-use-imports-depends check out the accepted answer

Comment: What is strange is that STRINGdb depends on igraph. When I just import STRINGdb, it doesnot work.

Comment: That's not strange - that's exactly what the answer says "There is one unfortunately common exception to the advice above: if your package relies on a package A which itself "Depends" on another package B, your package will likely need to attach A with a "Depends directive.""