# requireNamespace not loading required function

Tags: r, r-package

I am using [`neuralnet`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/index.html) to train neural networks. The package, more specifically the plotting function of `neuralnet`, depends on `grid`, which is a base package since last year. However, unless I load `grid` manually, the plotting fails:

```
AND <- c(rep(0,7),1)
OR <- c(0,rep(1,7))
binary.data <- data.frame(expand.grid(c(0,1), c(0,1), c(0,1)), AND, OR)
net <- neuralnet::neuralnet(AND + OR ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3, binary.data, 
                       hidden = 0, linear.output=FALSE)

if(requireNamespace("grid")) {
  neuralnet::plot.nn(net)
}

> Error in plot.nn(net, rep = i, x.entry, x.out, radius, arrow.length, intercept,  : 
> could not find function "grid.newpage"
```

Using `library(grid)` helps, but I want to avoid that because I want to use it in my own package later. [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) suggests using `requireNamespace`, but that doesn't help either, as we can see above.

Adding `grid::` in front of all calls to `grid` functions and building the package from source solves the issue, but I'm wondering: is that intended behavior? Looking at the sources of `neuralnet`, I find no mention of `requireNamespace`, `library` or similar. But then why doesn't *my* `requireNamespace` take care of loading the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that **neuralnet** only *depends* on the **grid** package, when it should instead (or at least also) *import* it. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8638902/980833) for one discussion of the difference between the two.)

As a result, when a function in **neuralnet** calls `grid.newpage()`, it will only be able to find that function *if **grid** is attached to the search path*. But a fully qualified call to `neuralnet::neuralnet()` does not attach **neuralnet**, which would trigger attachment of **grid**; and without **grid** on the search path, it has no idea what `grid.newpage` is.

To import **grid** into **neuralnet**, add this line to the source package's `NAMESPACE` file

```
import(grid)
```

and this line to its `DESCRIPTION` file

```
Imports: grid
```

and then recompile it.

Comment: Thanks. Now, when I publish my package people will use the `neuralnet` package from CRAN, not my compiled version. Could I bypass the issue from my code, e.g. using `attachNamespace`?

Comment: @sebastianmm As mentioned in my other answer, linked above (and in the answer to which *it* points) by far the best thing to do is to contact the package maintainers and ask them to have their package import **grid**. You can even supply them with the lines they need to add, and let them know that you've tested it and that it works. Other than that, I think you're stuck with having to Depend on **neuralnet** so that it'll load **grid** when it's attached, which is unfortunate.

Comment: So I just need to move neuralnet from `Imports` to `Depends`? I will contact the maintainer, anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to do both things mentioned in my answer. (The line in the `NAMESPACE` file is actually in many ways the more important of the two, though both are needed for a package on CRAN.) If for some reason the package maintainers still want **grid** to be attached (as well as imported), I'm 95% sure they would do *that* by leaving it as a `Depends:` in the `DESCRIPTION` file. (The only other possibility is that it would be entered in both the `Depends:` and `Imports:` field in `DESCRIPTION`.) If they don't actually want **grid** to be attached, then just move it from `Depends:` to `Imports:`.

Comment: But in **any** case, add `import(grid)` (or potentially a series of `importFrom()` directives) to the `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: Sorry, I think we got two solutions mixed: (1) your answer above (recompile `neuralnet` with grid import) **OR** (2) move `neuralnet` from `Imports` to `Depends` in *my* package. Both solutions seem to work.

Comment: Yep. Either one works, though the first one is cleaner. (If you `Depends` on **neuralnet** in your package, after all, then anybody who wants to use functions from your package in their own package will need to `Depend` on it, attaching your package and **neuralnet** and **grid**. Pretty soon, just using one function from one package means folks have to load and attach many other packages, which is a real pain.)