# avoid packages in Depends section while building your own package

Tags: r, namespaces, package

To be clear I have read through the brilliant answer by JoshO'Brien  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637993/better-explanation-of-when-to-use-imports-depends)
As mentioned in his edits, I have this exception case :

My package `A` uses a function `f1()` from package `gamlss` which is **Depend**ent on `gamlss.dist` alongwith 2 other packages. So if I had **Import**ed `gamlss`&`gamlss.dist` package and then called `f1()` then it would error out because gamlss.dist wasn't loaded in the NAMESPACE of `gamlss` since both were in **Depends**.( am i right in my understanding?)

So my question is , is there a way to avoid this error without having those 2 packages in **Depends**. (actually we might just need to have `gamlss` since it will load `gamlss.dist` by itself)

Basically my target is to avoid as much as possible in the **Depends** section. Let me know if more clarification is required.

Comment: @konvas if i have it in DEPENDS thwen no error at all. My motive was to avoid packages in Depends actually. would there be a way for it?

Comment: if i have `gamlss` in the `Imports` then error throws out because `gamlss()` fom gamlss package is dependent on `gamlsss.dist` and since we `import`ed gamlss, `gamlss.dist` is not found in its NAMESPACE as even Josh mentions in his answer in above link

Comment: ahh the answer that i was afraid to hear :( @konvas

Comment: If you import a function that imports functions from other packages, those secondary dependencies are obviously required for installation and build but you do not have to mention them specifically.