# Stuck with definition of S3 method for autoplot

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2, r-s3

I'm stuck with defining S3 method for `autoplot`.

I have the following (full code [here](https://github.com/m0nhawk/bigobenchmark)):

```
#' Autoplot for bigobenchmark object
#'
#' @importFrom ggplot2 autoplot
#'
#' @param object
#'
#' @return A ggplot2 plot
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' # Create plot for benchmarks
#' library(ggplot2)
#' bench <- bigobenchmark(1:n, for(i in 1:n) for(i in 1:n) 1:n, args=seq(from=1, to=100, length.out = 50))
#' autoplot(bench)
autoplot.bigobenchmark <- function(object) {
  plt <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = object$benchmarks, ggplot2::aes(x=arg, y=mean, colour=expr))
  plt <- plt + ggplot2::geom_line()
  plt <- plt + ggplot2::geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=min, ymax=max))
  plt
}
```

As I understand now I should be able to run, but it fails:

```
> autoplot(test)
Error in autoplot(test) : could not find function "autoplot"
```

Why it doesn't found the function? I have a proper `@importFrom ggplot2 autoplot` and Roxygen produces correct `NAMESPACE`.

There is a `ggplot2` in `Imports` in `DESCRIPTION`.

I have no idea why it doesn't work and why I need to `library(ggplot2)` to use it.

Comment: `export` the `autoplot` function to make it available to the user.

Answer (score 6):

When you import a package, it's "loaded via a namespace (and not attached)" (quoting from `sessionInfo()`).

When you want to use a function from an imported package you typically call it using the structure `ggplot2::ggplot()`, as you have done.

Therefore, to use `autoplot` you would still need to use `ggplot2::autoplot()`.

If you don't, your package is not aware of the `autoplot` function from `ggplot2`.

There are a few solutions to this:

1. use `Depends: ggplot2` (see links below for a discussion on `Imports` vs `Depends`, and [section 1.1.3 or writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies)]
2. define a `plot` method which then calls the various `ggplot2::ggplot()` functions
3. continue with `autoplot.bigobenchmark`, but require the user to load `ggplot2` prior to use (an example of this in practice is in [the zoo package](https://github.com/cran/zoo/blob/4228a000d3c5b591ca348c5a4dfbfe7295e71c7c/R/ggplot2.zoo.R#L51). See also `?zoo::autoplot`
4. Export your own `autoplot` function, but this may cause conflict if the user then later loads ggplot2

---

Here's an example of solution 2

```
#' plot for bigobenchmark object
#'
#' @importFrom ggplot2 autoplot
#'
#' @param object
#'
#' @return A ggplot2 plot
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' # Create plot for benchmarks
#' library(ggplot2)
#' bench <- bigobenchmark(1:n, for(i in 1:n) for(i in 1:n) 1:n, args=seq(from=1, to=100, length.out = 50))
#' plot(bench)
#'
#' @author Andrew Prokhorenkov
plot.bigobenchmark <- function(object) {
  plt <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = object$benchmarks, ggplot2::aes(x=arg, y=mean, colour=expr))
  plt <- plt + ggplot2::geom_line()
  plt <- plt + ggplot2::geom_pointrange(ggplot2::aes(ymin=min, ymax=max))
  plt
}
```

---

And here's an example of solution 4

```
#' Autoplot for bigobenchmark object
#'
#' @importFrom ggplot2 autoplot
#'
#' @param object
#'
#' @return A ggplot2 plot
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' # Create plot for benchmarks
#' library(ggplot2)
#' bench <- bigobenchmark(1:n, for(i in 1:n) for(i in 1:n) 1:n, args=seq(from=1, to=100, length.out = 50))
#' autoplot(bench)
#'
#' @author Andrew Prokhorenkov
autoplot <- function(object) UseMethod("autoplot")

#' @export
autoplot.bigobenchmark <- function(object) {
  plt <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = object$benchmarks, ggplot2::aes(x=arg, y=mean, colour=expr))
  plt <- plt + ggplot2::geom_line()
  plt <- plt + ggplot2::geom_pointrange(ggplot2::aes(ymin=min, ymax=max))
  plt
}
```

---

A better explanation of `Imports` vs `Depends` is given by Josh O'Brian and majom (quoting Hadley) in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8638902/5977215)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @SymbolixAU's response, you can import `autoplot` from `ggplot2` and export it like this, there will be no conflict with `ggplot2`:

```
#' bigobenchmark exported operators and S3 methods
#'
#' The following functions are imported and then re-exported
#' from the bigobenchmark  package to avoid loading them.
#'
#' @importFrom ggplot2 autoplot
#' @name autoplot
#' @export
NULL
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about this approach. I even use it to [export the pipe in one of my pacakges](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/R/googleway-package.R#L13). This is probably the best solution.

Comment: Yes! I use this for the pipe too the first time