# syntactic sugar || check fails for '.' || how do I import it or set global variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, global-variables, devtools

`#create package`

```
devtools::create("./brainy",rstudio=F)

usethis::use_package("dplyr", type = "import", min_version = TRUE) ## set dependancy
```

I've a small function where I use `%>%` from `dplyr`. Also I use `.` when piping. I do not know where is `.` imported from or how to achieve its alignment when `check()`ing the package

My small R code looks like in :

```
add<-function(x,y){ 
#' Package provides sample data that are loaded with package loading. 
#' @param a and y are variables
#' #not RUN
#' @importFrom dplyr %>%

data_test<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1:10)), NAME=c(paste("ID",seq(1:10),sep="_")))

data_test$NAME<-data_test$NAME %>%  gsub("_*","",.) # for getting warning about .

return(x+y)

}
```

There is a test data I create for asking the question and to reproduce it.

I run following things:

```
devtools::document()  
devtools::check()
```

I get warning as:

```
  add: no visible binding for global variable ‘.’
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    .
```

How do I set my code where it achieves agreement with `check()` with the `.`. The resource below suggests to put into the globalVariables, but where (function, file) do I set the global variable at?

Hopefully, last question - which of the following should I use and why:

`usethis::use_package("dplyr", type = "Depends", min_version = TRUE)`

`usethis::use_package("dplyr", type = "import", min_version = TRUE)`

https://www.r-bloggers.com/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable/

Tool versions

`dplyr_1.0.0`
`usethis_1.6.1`
`devtools_2.3.1`
`rmarkdown_2.3`
`R 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)`

Comment: Try `utils::globalVariables`? I have however not met issues with using `.` before. What's your `dplyr` version? See an example [here](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/mde/search?q=global&type=). For your Depends vs imports question, only use Depends if your package cannot work without `dplyr` or if it significantly depends on `dplyr`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, yes my library cannot function without dplyr, I'll have `depend` within it. I've edited my post with addition of R libraries and their versions.

Comment: Looks fine although I personally would put it in imports since most people will have `dplyr` either way. Hadley is [quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31962488/10323798) as suggesting `Imports`. Do you have a link to your package's code? It's a bit odd that you need to define `.` globally.

Comment: No, I don't have link to the package. It is a small package. Would you be able to follow the steps I performed above from create and a script `small_function.R` with code and function name as is to reproduce?

Comment: Oh, I see what the issue is. Why do you want to use `.` with `gsub`? It can only be understood inside `dplyr` functions and not outside. Here `gsub` would expect something like dataframe names or just df$NAME. If you want to stick to `tidy` syntax, then use `mutate` and friends with `stringr` but this adds more dependencies. And maybe do not use `$` if you want to use the pipe?

Comment: I see, makes sense. I edited code for `gsub`. However, that is only tip of the ice-berg in the function I've many lines of code where `.` is used while processing data of `data.table` class. For example: `dt_gene<-data.table(ID=c(seq(1:10)),SNP=c(paste("SNPA",seq(1:10),sep="_")))` 

`dt_gene %>%  .[, c("SNP") := "SNP_names" ] `

Comment: @NelsonGon if you can post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I have added an answer. It somehow became more complicated than I initially thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I turn my comments into an answer since these may also help someone else in the future.

It is normally possible to go around the **no visible binding for global variable** error by defining the variable with `utils::globalVariables`. Unfortunately that won't work with `.`.

Instead, one should stick to `tidyverse`-like syntax and use alternatives like `mutate` or `.data`. In `tidyverse` style, `add`(named `add_fn` here to avoid name conflicts) can be rewritten as follows:

```
add_fn<-function(x,y){
  #' Package provides sample data that are loaded with package loading.
  #' @param x some variable
  #' @param y another variable
  #' @importFrom dplyr %>% mutate


  data_test<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1:10)),
                        NAME=c(paste("ID",seq(1:10),sep="_")))

  data_test<-data_test %>%
       mutate({{NAME = gsub("_*","",NAME)}})

  return(x+y)

}
```

The above uses `{{}}` from `rlang` to parse `NAME` via non standard evaluation.

Alternatively, in this specific example, one does not need to use the `tidyverse` at all:

```
add_fn<-function(x,y){
  #' Package provides sample data that are loaded with package loading.
  #' @param x some variable
  #' @param y another variable
  #' @importFrom dplyr %>% mutate


  data_test<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1:10)),
                        NAME=c(paste("ID",seq(1:10),sep="_")))

  data_test$NAME<-gsub("_*","",data_test$NAME)

  return(x+y)

}
```

Check results:

```
-- R CMD check results ------------------------------------- brainy 0.0.0.9000 ----
Duration: 1m 38.7s

0 errors √ | 0 warnings √ | 0 notes √
```