# Buidling R package with issue loading data.table ".()" function

Tags: r, data.table, dependencies, devtools, roxygen2

when building an R package that uses data.table as an attached package, the list() function of data.table ".()" always gives the error could not find function ".". While other functions from data.table were all recognized. Here is my .R page for the function that uses data.table:

```
#' Advanced Bar Plot with Statistics
#'
#' Creates an advanced bar plot with mean and standard error for specified categories
#' using ggplot2.
#'
#' @param data_frame A data frame containing the data for plotting.
#' @param col The name of the column for calculating statistics.
#' @param category1 The primary category for grouping data.
#' @param category2 The secondary category for grouping data (default is "Memory").
#' @param title The title for the plot (default is the value of category1).
#' @return A ggplot2 bar plot object with error bars.
#' @import data.table
#' @examples
#' df <- data.table(value = rnorm(100), dx = sample(c("Group1", "Group2"), 100, replace = TRUE), Memory = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))
#' quick_bar_plot2(df, "value", "dx", "Memory")
quick_bar_plot2 <- function(data_frame, col, category1, category2 = "Memory", title = category1){
  setDT(data_frame)

  # Dynamic column names: compute mean and standard error
  col_stats <- data_frame[, .(Mean_col = mean(get(col), na.rm = TRUE),
                              SE = sd(get(col), na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(.N)),
                          by = c(category1, category2)]

  col_stats[, (category2) := factor(get(category2), levels = c(1, 0), labels = c("Impaired", "Not Impaired"))]

  # Create the plot
  # print(class(col_stats[[category2]]))
  # print(levels(col_stats[[category2]]))
  ggplot(col_stats, aes_string(x = category1, y = "Mean_col", fill = category2)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean_col - SE, ymax = Mean_col + SE),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.25) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = category2, values = c("Impaired" = "#F8766D", "Not Impaired" = "#00BA38")) +
    # scale_fill_manual(name = category2, values = colors)
    labs(title = paste("Mean", gsub("_", " ", col), "by", title, "and", category2), # \n
         x = " ",
         y = paste("Mean", col)) +
    theme_minimal()
  # print(plot)
}
```

The function works fine when just using independently, but when I include it as a function in my R package, I got the following example error:

```
### ** Examples

df <- data.table(value = rnorm(100), dx = sample(c("Group1", "Group2"), 100, replace = TRUE), Memory = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))
quick_bar_plot2(df, "value", "dx", "Memory")
Error in .(Mean_col = mean(get(col), na.rm = TRUE), SE = sd(get(col), : could not find function "."
```

Comment: Have you tried building it without the example? If it builds, then it's something about the example run that doesn't import the entire data.table namespace.

Comment: `.()` is alias for `list()` right?. So try with: 
`col_stats <- data_frame[, list(Mean_col = mean(get(col), na.rm = TRUE),
                               SE = sd(get(col), na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(.N)),
                        by = c(category1, category2)]`

Comment: I tried building it without the example, but the same error occurs when I test it, so not working. I also tried using list instead of . , but then there is a series of issues such as col was not recognized and then .N was not recognized, so also not working. I also tried upgrade data.table to the latest version, still not working :(

Comment: Try adding the roxygen tag `@importFrom data.table .N` . Do this also for the other symbols if you wish, `:=`, `.GRP`, `.SD` and use `list()` in place of `.()`

Comment: Is it safe to assume that 'data.table' is listed in the depends section of the description file?

Comment: Yes, here is what my description file shows: Imports: data.table, dplyr, ggplot2, purrr

Comment: I tried replace .() with list() and added @importFrom data.table .N, but get this error now: @importFrom data.table .N  `@NicChr`

Comment: I was a bit confused because you specified that data.table is an attached package. For that to be the case you should add it to the Depends section of your description file instead of the Imports section. I would suggest to remove the '@importfrom' statements, restart R, add data.table to the Depends section, run `devtools::document()` as well as `devtools::load_all()` and hopefully that will work.

Comment: Have you set `.datatable.aware <- TRUE` in your package? That's generally required per the `data.table` FAQ to get all functionality inside a different package.

Comment: `@NicChr` you are right. changing "import" to "depends" solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Using `Depends` has consequences, it is not the recommended way to go, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8638902/3358272. @NicChr

Comment: Agree @r2evans, it's not my recommended approach either. I have a package that uses data.table without issues by simply importing the specific functions I need.

Comment: One more thing @LCheng.. If you absolutely have to attach data.table, it's recommended to include it and it alone in the Depends section, while keeping the Imports section. Otherwise your users will see unintended function conflicts when they try to use a function from say dplyr that has the same name as one in data.table (or vice versa).

Comment: Still no. It is _not_ recommended to include `data.table`, alone or otherwise, in Depends. It is recommended to put it in Imports. Doing so may require adding `.datatable.aware <- TRUE` in your package (top level, not inside a function). Other packages do this just fine and have access to `.` and all other `data.table` functionality. Adding it to Depends might work on your local computer in testing but is likely to cause unwanted problems in common usage patterns. If you (LCheng) are the only user of this package, have at it, otherwise caveat emptor. Good luck.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case I was mistaken.