# Package imports error on devtools::check()

Tags: r, package

I have a package that contains the following package Imports in the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Imports: lubridate,
    assertthat,
    R6,
    stringr
```

I **don't** import these into my package's NAMESPACE using an `import(pkgname)` or `importFrom(pkgname, fn)` commands. Rather I refer to these package's functions in my R code using a fully qualified call. Based on my reading of [R-ext](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies), this is permissible:

> The ‘Imports’ field lists packages whose namespaces are imported from (as specified in the NAMESPACE file) but which do not need to be attached. Namespaces accessed by the ‘::’ and ‘:::’ operators must be listed here...

However, I get the following error when I run `devtools::check()`:

```
* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
Namespaces in Imports field not imported from:
  'R6' 'stringr'
  All declared Imports should be used.
See the information on DESCRIPTION files in the chapter 'Creating R
packages' of the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
```

NB: to confirm, my R code contains fully qualified calls to functions in R6 and stringr (e.g. `stringr::str_detect(...)` and `R6::R6Class(...)`).

Why am I getting these notes? And how do I make them go away?

Comment: I'm hiding my post until I'm sure it has correct details. However, I still think adding `importFrom` will remove the note, please try that.

Comment: Related: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637993/better-explanation-of-when-to-use-imports-depends), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893791/imports-and-depends) (see question 4), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085481/namespace-dependencies-not-required).

Comment: Thanks @tonytonov. I know about importFrom(), but I don't want to use that mechanism as the R-ext docs suggest I don't need to. The links you've provided don't address my use case.

Comment: Keep in mind you are getting a note, not an error. So if your approach works, leave it be and ignore the note. However, your package will not be accepted on CRAN, they have a strict policy on that.

Comment: I also get the same error using ggvis in the same way but not other for other packages whose methods I call using `::`

Comment: I believe you need at least one import to please R CMD check. But that does not prevent you from using fully qualified calls.

Comment: Have you checked my above comment ? You could may be close that issue...