# R with roxygen2: How to use a single function from another package?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm creating an R package that will use **a single function** from `plyr`. According to [this roxygen2 vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html):

> If you are using just a few functions from another package, the
>   recommended option is to note the package name in the Imports: field
>   of the DESCRIPTION file and call the function(s) explicitly using ::,
>   e.g., pkg::fun().

That sounds good. I'm using `plyr::ldply()` - the full call with `::` - so I list `plyr` in `Imports:` in my `DESCRIPTION` file. However, when I use `devtools::check()` I get this:

```
* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
All declared Imports should be used:
  ‘plyr’
  All declared Imports should be used.
```

*Why do I get this note?*

I am able to avoid the note by adding `@importFrom dplyr ldply` in the file that is using `plyr`, but then I end but having `ldply` in my package namespace. Which I do not want, and should not need as I am using `plyr::ldply()` the single time I use the function.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335991/package-imports-error-on-devtoolscheck) might be relevant.)

Comment: Is `roxygen2` overwriting your `NAMESPACE` file?  I believe you need to have `@import dplyr` to make sure it is added automatically.

Comment: Thank you for answering. `roxygen2` is indeed updating my `NAMESPACE` file. I do not want to use `@import dplyr`, because that imports the whole namespace of dplyr. According to the `roxygen2` vignette and the other question I referred to I shouldn't need to import it either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*If `ldply()` is important for your package's functionality*, then you do want it in your package namespace. That is the point of namespace imports. Functions that you need, should be in the package namespace because this is where R will look first for the definition of functions, before then traversing the base namespace and the attached packages. It means that no matter what other packages are loaded or unloaded, attached or unattached, your package will always have access to that function. In such cases, use:

```
@importFrom plyr ldply
```

And you can just refer to `ldply()` without the `plyr::` prefix just as if it were another function in your package.

*If `ldply()` is not so important* - perhaps it is called only once in a not commonly used function - then, [Writing R Extensions 1.5.1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports) gives the following advice:

> If a package only needs a few objects from another package it can use a fully qualified variable reference in the code instead of a formal import. A fully qualified reference to the function `f` in package `foo` is of the form `foo::f`. This is slightly less efficient than a formal import and also loses the advantage of recording all dependencies in the `NAMESPACE` file (but they still need to be recorded in the `DESCRIPTION` file). Evaluating `foo::f` will cause package `foo` to be loaded, but not attached, if it was not loaded already—this can be an advantage in delaying the loading of a rarely used package.

(I think this advice is actually a little outdated because it is implying more separation between `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` than currently exists.) It implies you should use `@import plyr` and refer to the function as `plyr::ldply()`. But in reality, it's actually suggesting something like putting `plyr` in the `Suggests` field of `DESCRIPTION`, which isn't exactly accommodated by roxygen2 markup nor exactly compliant with `R CMD check`.

*In sum*, the official line is that Hadley's advice (which you are quoting) is only preferred for rarely used functions from rarely used packages (and/or packages that take a considerable amount of time to load). Otherwise, just do `@importFrom` like *WRE* advises:

> Using `importFrom` selectively rather than `import` is good practice and recommended notably when importing from packages with more than a dozen exports.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem arises when I use `@import packagename` for two packages that has functions with the same name. `devtools::check()` then gives something like this: "Found the following significant warnings: Warning: replacing previous import ‘IRanges::desc’ by ‘plyr::desc’ when loading ‘mypackage’". Of course this can be avoiding by specifying the imports with `@importFrom`. But what about the extremely odd case where you need a function called `foo` from `packageA` **and** the function called `foo` from `packageB`? When importing both, `check()` will complain. Right?

Comment: @L42 That's the reason to use `importFrom`. In the rare case you mention, there will be an R CMD check complaint. One solution might be to import a different function from `packageB` (e.g., `importFrom(packageB, bar)` to ensure the package is installed and its namespace is loaded, then refer to `packageB::foo()` in your code w/o importing `foo`. Another solution would be to create a new single-function package that basically renames the duplicated function with something like: `newname <- function(...) packageB::foo(...)` and then import that.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems to me now that it's impossible to have a package listed in `Imports` in the `DESCRIPTION` file and **not** have it listed in the `NAMESPACE` file. Is my understanding correct? If so, then I think the `roxygen2` vignette and the `Writing R Extensions` guide should to clearly state this.