# Use new() without loading the respective package beforehand in R

Tags: r, new-operator

I am trying to find the best way to use this pedigree class without using library  `pedigreemm` first.

```
p1 <- new("pedigree",
          sire = as.integer(c(NA,NA,1, 1,4,5)),
          dam  = as.integer(c(NA,NA,2,NA,3,2)),
          label = as.character(1:6))
```

> Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) :
>   “pedigree” is not a defined class

To be clear, I am trying to do something like `base::mean()`. However, as the `new()` function do not belong to the `pedigreemm` package seems to be not that straightforward. Thus, I can't just do `pedigreemm::new()`. It is important to highlight that the code works just fine if I load the `pedigreemm` package first, but I need a way to run without loading it first. Any ideas?

Comment: Might not be possible... can you explain *why* you need to do this? We may be able to help you find a better solution to the root problem.

Comment: It is a function inside a package. Thus, package::function is always preferred.

Comment: Have you tried to add `@importClassesFrom pedigreemm pedigree` if using `roxygen2`? If the class is defined in another package, then I think the only option available is to import the class.

Comment: Also, I don't think using `package::function` is *always* prefered. As an example: if you intend to use `ggplot2` functions in a package, then calling `ggplot2::function` will make the code long and hard to read as you end up using many functions together (i.e. `aes`, `ggplot`, `geom_*`, `scale_*`, etc). While you could import those functions and have a shorter and more legible code.

Comment: @Freguglia, could you give an example on how to wisely import functions?

Comment: Of course: If you're using `roxygen2`, then simply add a line with `#' @importFrom package function` somewhere in your code. You also need to add the imported package to the `Imports` section in the description file. Here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574141/r-with-roxygen2-how-to-use-a-single-function-from-another-package